# SOAP UI - Set custom property to a test case after the REST request test step

Tags: soapui

I need to set a custom property from a test case lets say `TestCase #1`,

This `TestCase#1` has a [Rest request test step](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/steps/rest-request.html)

These are the 2 different steps,
1.Rest Request Test Step
2.Set Custom property

After this step executes, in the next step via Groovy script I would like to access the previous step's response, parse and set custom property to the test case or test suite.

I am setting a value to test suite via this code,

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("someName", someValue)
```

This is the code that I will be using in the `step #2` to set up a custom property.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

def config = jsonSlurper.parse('JSON response from previous step object here'))
def someValue=config.apiVals.someJSONProperty[0].id as String
```

The above can be achieved using script assertions in the same `step #1` but I don't want to do over there.

I want to parse the response in the next step with some additional processing.

how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can do this with a "Property Transfer" test step.

Answer (score 0):

Within REST Request, we get a response which is a JSON Object:

[image]

and when we want to transfer this response with Property Tranfer: we can leave Source text field empty and we will tranfer the whole JSON object, if we want to tranfer a data of this object which is in this case name we set the source text field $.name and we are now able to retrieve a specific data of the JSON object.

[image]